# JLabel text is garbled

Tags: java, swing, character-encoding, jlabel, off-by-one

I'm seeing a strange issue involving a `JLabel` that is used to display a range of numbers. The text of the label is typically something like **0.0 - 100.0** (for example). The problem is that for a select few users, the text appears garbled. In this example, the text would show up as **/-/,0//-/**.

Here's what I know so far:

- It appears to be some sort of off-by-one bug since each character displayed is one Unicode character behind the expected character.
- The dash character between the two numbers is hard-coded in the application as a string literal.
- It's happening on various versions of Oracle JVMs including 1.6.x and 1.7.x.
- It's happening on a few select Windows 7 machines.

What could cause this type of problem? What else should I investigate? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue myself. The code is pretty simple. It's basically just setting the text of the label using two numbers that have been formatted using a NumberFormat and a dash that's a string literal.

Comment: So you don't have access to the code?  It's pretty difficult to diagnose without it.

Comment: We have a similar problem with our java editor josm (see https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/8488). I have two questions for you: Does your JLabel use a custom font, and what locales have the users.

Comment: @DirkStöcker, your issue appears to be the exact same thing. My label does have a font explicitly set (Arial plain 12pt.). I can confirm locales on Monday, but they're likely en_US and en_CA. I'm leaning towards it being a font issue because we don't see the issue with most other labels in the app.

Comment: Two more things that could explain this bug:

* Users may have installed **gdipp** (alternative Windows font renderer) that suffers [a similar bug](https://code.google.com/p/gdipp/issues/detail?id=155).

* Corruptions in the **Windows font cache** (%WINDIR%\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT) sometimes cause similar behaviour. Users should try to delete this file and reboot their PC.

Comment: @vip, I'm going to have one of the users clear the font cache on Monday. I'll update later with the results.

Comment: @vip, clearing the font cache fixed the issue! Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you're setting the font of your `JLabel` to a font corrupted in the Windows font cache.

To rebuild the cache: as administrator, delete this file and reboot the PC:

```
del %WINDIR%\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an errant `DateFormat`, instances of which are "are generally not synchronized." If it's intermittent, rather than selective, verify correct use of  [`invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), and "create separate format instances for each thread." See also [`Format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html).

Addendum: The errant symbols might arise from the `DateFormatSymbols` or `DecimalFormatSymbols` used by concrete subclasses of `Format`. You can verify correct use of the event dispatch thread in several ways:

- Examine the result of `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`.
- Employ one of the schemes shown in the articles cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).
- Inspect the source code following the principles summarized in [*Memory Consistency Properties*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility).

As you cannot reproduce the problem, you will have to enlist the help of your users. Ideally, you will want to solicit the following:

- Host name, platform, locale & JVM version from `System.getProperty()`?
- Intermittent or consistent?
- [Screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)?

You can make it easier for the user by filling in some details in a message prepared using `Desktop#mail()`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15817368/230513).

Comment: I'm not following your answer. Can you elaborate more? There is no DateFormat involved, just a NumberFormat. Also, why would the string literal dash be off-by-one in the label if this had anything to do with the format object? I think it's likely something related to a strange system configuration or locale thing, no?